# Adding Bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10 to Explorer Context Menu (Issues)

Tags: windows-10, command-line, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-10-v1607

I have successfully added the Bash on Ubuntu prompt to the context menu by adding the following registry keys

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\bash]
@="Bash Here"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\bash\command]
@="C:\\Windows\\System32\\bash.exe"
```

Now, the above solution has <del>two major issues</del> one issue which I do not know how to address.

The problem is that the path to which it launches is actually that of the parent directory, not the one being right clicked.

I tried including additional arguments to the launch command, however, that results in the prompt being closed immediately before even having a chance to read any error information.

The default command from the shortcut `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe ~` does indeed work and put me in `/home/user/`

UPDATE: It seems that executing `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe` uses a set of settings stored under `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%SystemRoot%_system32_bash.exe]` as well as some (colors for instance) from the default location `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console]`, so once those settings are saved they do successfully reload. Whereas, the shortcut created on install seems to use the settings assigned to `cmd.exe` (to be confirmed)

UPDATE 2: Please do not offer solutions involving launching `bash.exe` from inside `cmd.exe`

Comment: To anyone who arrived to this question when searching for the path to add to Windows Path variable for bash.exe, it's c:\Windows\Sysnative. It's a tricky one.

Answer (score 2):

An easy fix to this is to run through cmd. This command sets the current working directory to the selected folder and then launches bash.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Bash]
@="Bash Here"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Bash\command]
@="C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe /k cd %1 && C:\\windows\\system32\\bash.exe"
```

Tested and working, just save the above code into a text file and rename the extension to `.reg`

If you want to exit after instead of dropping back into CMD just type `&& exit` at the end of the command

Comment: If you want to exit afterwards you could also change the `/k` to `/c`.

Comment: This does indeed work, however, it launches off of the cmd.exe settings (obviously) and uses the same icon in the upper left, any way around this?

Comment: Does not work for mapped drives.

Comment: Do you see the mapped network drives in `/mnt` ? Have a look at https://superuser.com/a/1136369/624775 it appears network drives have only just been included.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a step-by-step tutorial how to do this on this page: http://winaero.com/blog/add-bash-to-the-folder-context-menu-in-windows-10/

Additionally they offer ready-to-use registry files. I tested the registry files and they work on my Win10 x64 system.

Comment: Please include the core of the included link in your answer. That way, people will be able to use it even if the link goes down for some reason. [Here's a meta discussion about why you should include the important details in your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259)

Comment: The instructions in that blog post amount to the previous answer with the same inherent issues.