# Getting `sshfs` working on WSL or finding an alternative

Tags: filesystems, sftp, windows-subsystem-for-linux, sshfs, fuse

My university's CS department has its own server used for development (from here on out, `dev.univ.edu`). I have SSH and SFTP access to this server, and I was hoping to do some heavy work on my Windows laptop using WSL. My plan was to use `sshfs` to mount the server's filesystem on my laptop via SFTP, so that I could use my own tools instead of having to use the limited programs on our server. However, whenever I try using `sshfs`, the following happens:

```
user@host:~$ sshfs -p 22 user@dev.univ.edu: ~/dev/ -o follow_symlinks
> fuse: device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first
```

Running `modprobe fuse` gives me the following result:

```
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.4.0-43-Microsoft/modules.dep.bin'
modprobe: FATAL: Module fuse not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-43-Microsoft
```

After some digging, it seems that [`fuse` is not supported on WSL](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/17), even after the [UserVoice page](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-windows-subsystem-for-l/suggestions/13522845-add-fuse-filesystem-in-userspace-support-in-wsl) for `fuse` support has been up for over 2 years with over 1500 people asking for it. Since `sshfs` relies on `fuse` (I assume for creating the filesystem that the remote files sit in), this renders `sshfs` unusable.

I have found a project ([`billziss-gh/winfsp`](https://github.com/billziss-gh/winfsp)) that seems promising, but I have no idea how to implement it in combination with `sshfs`. Is there someone more knowledgeable than I am that can help me get this working?

EDIT: According to [this issue](https://github.com/billziss-gh/winfsp/issues/61), `winfsp` will not work with WSL. However, I noticed a project by the same guy ([`billziss-gh/nfs-win`](https://github.com/billziss-gh/nfs-win)) that might be useful.

Comment: Until a good sshfs filesystem implementation has been created for window have you considered using git? creat repo on server, clone to desktop over ssh and push changes back to the server as you make them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since I asked this question, Microsoft has released WSL 2 in its Insiders Preview ring. Since this provides a full Linux kernel to WSL, no more workarounds are necessary to get SSHFS to work.

**Update:** WSL 2 is now publicly available as of Windows version 2004. Have fun!

Comment: There's problem with sshfs and fuse. See issue page: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL2-Linux-Kernel/issues/58

Comment: What is gonna happen when the system restart?(or WSL restart for some reason) do you have to mount again the folder manually?

Answer (score 14):

So I have a workaround that you might like. I installed [SFTP Net Drive 2017](https://www.nsoftware.com/sftp/netdrive/)  and then remotely connected to the file system I wanted. I mapped it (via the GUI) as `R:\`. From WSL, you can then map `R:\` to a local folder as explained [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2017/04/18/file-system-improvements-to-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux/).

So in WSL, I have a folder in my home directory called `cluster`. To mount it to be my local home from my cluster, I run:

```
sudo mount -t drvfs R: ~/cluster
```

and to unmount it, I run

```
umount ~/cluster
```

for convenience, I made an alias called `mc`, sourced it from my `.bashrc`

```
alias mc="sudo umount ~/cluster; sudo mount -t drvfs R: ~/cluster"
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Are you still using this approach?  Do you have any problems with file permissions or data coherence?

Comment: How do permissions work?