# How to access files on network drive from Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: windows, windows-10, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using Windows 10 version 1903 OS Build 18362.356 and WSL (Ubuntu 18.04). I can access files in my C: drive just fine, however there is a a drive under the "Network" section on windows explorer that I can't find anywhere.
I am aware that this has been asked here before but when I try the answer: https://superuser.com/a/1261563/1089317

i.e.:

```
$ sudo mkdir /mnt/share
$ sudo mount -t drvfs '\\server\share' /mnt/share
```

(which I did as 2 separate commands, the 1st one runs fine) and I get the error after the 2nd statement:

> mount: mnt/share: mount point does not exist.
>       <3>init: (5524) ERROR: UtilCreateProcessAndWait:360: /bin/mount failed with status 0x2000
>       No error information

any help will be very appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please specify what version of Windows 10 you are using, when you provide this information as an edit to your question, also include vital information about your WSL environment.  In the accepted answer to the possible duplicate, the author wrote the commands as two seperate command, but you wrote them as a single command.  Is there a reason?  Before running the 2nd command did you verify the mkdir was sucessfull?  You are doing this as root I presume?

Comment: I did run them as 2 separate commands and the first one now says "mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/share’: File exists" when I try to run it again which I assume means it has worked.
I'm using the sudo command at the start, is that different to doing it as root?
Thanks

Comment: What vital information about my WSL environment? I'm using Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Mainly your Windows 10 version and the WSL distribution which you provided only 3 hours ago.

Comment: You should take the time to properly format the command you ran in that case.

Answer (score 9):

Edit:
run:
net.exe - I believe this located the shared drives

Run `sudo mkdir /mnt/share`

Run `sudo mount -t drvfs '\\server\share' /mnt/share`

Note: `\\server\share` will be the name of your shared drive which you should be able to see when you run net.exe.

It worked for me after that, just `cd` to `/mnt/share` and all the files should be accessible now.

It has worked now, I had to use the command net.exe first and then it did find the shared drives. But it looks like I have to run the command `sudo mount -t drvfs '\\server\share' /mnt/share` every session, which I guess is not the end of the world. Just annoying.

Comment: Provide all the steps and command with some details. It will help others who have same issue as yours.

Comment: `mount: /mnt/Share: bad option; for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program.`

Comment: just typing `net.exe use` from WSL will list network drives

Comment: you can then choose one item from the list and do `sudo mount -t drvfs '\\Srv-xxyz\Somename' /mnt/share`

Answer (score -1):

Here is the OP's answer that was added to the question:

> It has worked now, I had to use the command net.exe first and then it did find the shared drives. But it looks like I have to run the command sudo mount -t drvfs '\server\share' /mnt/share every session, which I guess is not the end of the world. Just annoying.

Answer (score -3):

### Steps to Access Files on Network Drive from Windows Subsystem for Linux

Very simple steps to control files on Network Drive from WSL are as follows:

1. At first, tap down both the Windows and the letter E key at a time. This will open the File Explorer on the screen.
2. After that, from the left-hand side panel click on Linux and then
   hit on the Distros shortcut, that is present at the right-hand side of the window.
3. Next, open the running WSL distro (ex: Ubuntu) folder, to see the files that you want.
4. Further, double-click on the folder named as **Home** under the
   list, to open.
5. Now, open the  folder.

That's it.

Comment: These instructions are nonsensical...